# TSQL Select entire column as XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Hopefully this isn't too silly of a question.  I've been trying to find an answer for a bit now.

Suppose I have a table like so:

`MyTable`:

```
Name   NVARCHAR(25)
Data   XML
```

How can I select the entire column value as XML?

```
declare @XmlVar xml = (select top 1 Data from MyTable)
```

Does not seem to allow manipulation of that xml later on.

```
declare @XmlVar xml = (select top 1 Data from MyTable FOR XML AUTO)
```

Seems to append additional nodes (`<MyTable><Data>...`)

Comment: The directive `FOR XML AUTO` is used to turn non-XML data into XML. That's definitely not what you want here.

Comment: What kind of manipulation is it not allowing you to do?

Comment: @JonathanAllen set @XmlVar.modify('insert....') does not affect it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was not specifying the namespace required, and thus the Modify statement was not working.

So:

```
declare @XmlVar xml = (select top 1 Data from MyTable)
```

works fine.

```
@XmlVar.modify('declare default element namespace "MyNameSpaceUrl";
delete /RootNode[1]')
```

works when I specify the default element namespace as descibed in MyTable.Data.

Hope this saves someone else some time in the future.